# If Condition that Executes When Satisfies By an If Condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to Ignore the variables in IF condition which have the value "All".

Here are the conditions. $one and $two are `GET/POST` variables

**case1:** `If $one == 'All' and $two = 'Sometext'`

```
if($two == $DynamicValue2)
{
//display data
}
```

**Case2:**  `If $one == 'text' and $two = 'All '`

```
if($one== $DynamicValue1)
{
//display data
}
```

**Case3:** `If $one == 'text' and $two = 'text'`

```
if($one == $DynamicValue1 && $two == $DynamicValue2)
{
//Display Data
}
```

**Case4:** `If $one == 'All' and $two = 'All'`

```
No need to write/ Check IF condition here.
```

I tried the following code but doesn't work

```
if(isset($one) && $one!= 'All')
{
if($one == $DynamicValue1): // First IF
}

if(isset($two) && $two!= 'All')
{
if($two == $DynamicValue2): // Second IF
}

//dispaly data

if(isset($one) && $one!= 'All')
{
endif; // to close First IF condition
}

if(isset($two) && $two!= 'All')
{
endif; // to close Second IF condition
}
```

I thought the above code satisfies all the cases which I've mentioned here. But no use.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you indent your code to make it easier to understand how you want it to react?

Comment: you cant start a if statement in one if statement and end it in another if statement.

Comment: whats wrong with normal nested ifs? `if(cond){if(other){//do stuff}}`

Comment: You cannot conditionally open and close if statements. Simply nest your conditions logically inside regular `if (..) { if (..) { .. } }` blocks.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki `If` is not a looping statement.

Comment: why all the downvotes? this question shows an attempt to do something, and obviously the OP's lack of PHP experience has resulted in this..

Comment: I think you should grab a beginners book on Programming and start reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could able to resolve my issue.

```
if($one == 'All')
{
$one = $DynamicValue1;

}

if($two == 'All')
{
$two = $DynamicValue2

}
```

Then I write the condition like follows

```
if($one == $DynamicValue1 && $two == $DynamicValue2)

{

//my data here


}
```

So it satisfies all the conditions.

If `$one` has a value of '`All`' then it overwrites that value with `$DynamicValue1`. So it would be always true. If it's other than '`All`' It would check with `$DynamicValue1` in IF condition.

Similarly for variable `$two` also

I wrote this logic myself. I tested all scenarios and working fine.

Suggest me If I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine statements in one if:

```
if(isset($one) && $one!= 'All' && $one == $DynamicValue1 &&
    isset($two) && $one!= 'All' && $two == $DynamicValue2)
{
    //dispaly data
}
```

This code will check if isset $one variable and $one not equal to 'All' and $one equal to $DynamicValue1 and the same with $two variable

Comment: I think this condition wont' work if $one= 'All' and $two = 'All'

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do that?:

```
if(isset($one) && $one!= 'All') {
    if($one == $DynamicValue1) { 
        // make this
    }

    if (isset($two) && $two == $DynamicValue2) {
        // make that
    }
}
```